# Vue slot activator during tooltip is re-rendering my v-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to put a tooltip on a v-icon who randomly gets assigned a color. Every time I mouse over the v-icon, the color changes.  I only want the color to be set one time. I do not want the color to change every time the mouse is hovered over the v-icon.  Any suggestions?

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template #activator="{on}">
    <v-icon v-on="on" :color="getRandomColor()">mdi-close</v-icon>
  </template>
  <span>Some Tooltip text</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by making a color array in the data: section of Vue and generating the random colors there. Then, I just call that specific array index in color.  Something like this:

```
 data() {
   return {
     rColors: [getRandomColor(), getRandomColor()],
   }
 }
 <v-icon v-on="on" :color="rColors[0]">mdi-close</v-icon>
```

Is there a way to avoid doing this by putting a keyword in the previous code?

Something like

```
v-on:once="on" ?
```